# How can I nest this streamwriter within a while loop, wanting the button to be able to write infinitely

Tags: c#, arrays

```
   private void addTimeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"W:\out.txt"))
            {
                string[] denter code hereata = new string[4];
                data[0] = fNameBox.Text;
                data[1] = sNameBox.Text;
                data[2] = genderCheck.Text;
                data[3] = timeBox.Text;

                string myStringOutput = String.Join(",", data.Select(p => p.ToString()).ToArray());
                sw.Write(myStringOutput + "\n");
                myStringOutput += Environment.NewLine;
                sw.Close();
            }

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"W:\out.txt"))
            {
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    readTimeButton.AppendText(sr.ReadLine());
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm wanting to nest the stream writer within a while loop, similar to how to how the reader is, for some reason using the same method doesn't work. I basically want the button to be able to be pressed infinitely until the user decides they want to close the program.

Comment: *button to be able to be pressed infinitely* - what does this mean? What is a *press*, in your mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need to add an "sw.Close();" inside a using stream because the "using" will close the stream.
Why don't you include your stream writer inside a while loop like this?

```
private void addTimeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       while(true)
       {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"W:\out.txt"))
        {
            string[] denter code hereata = new string[4];
            data[0] = fNameBox.Text;
            data[1] = sNameBox.Text;
            data[2] = genderCheck.Text;
            data[3] = timeBox.Text;

            string myStringOutput = String.Join(",", data.Select(p => p.ToString()).ToArray());
            sw.Write(myStringOutput + "\n");
            myStringOutput += Environment.NewLine;
            // sw.Close(); // not necessary whithin a using
        }

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"W:\out.txt"))
        {
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                readTimeButton.AppendText(sr.ReadLine());
                Application.DoEvents(); // to see your text increasing
            }
        }
      }
    }
```

The AppendText method doesn't belong to a button control.

Can you explain what you are trying to do?